# Adding instance to a list creates similar values

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have an instance of a class that needs to be appended to a list. However, upon appending N amount of instances, the values of the list is the last inserted instance.

Here is a replication of what I'm trying to do (Original file is big):

```
class SomeParent:
  listOfObject = []
  tempObject = None

  def addObjects(self):
    for i in range(10):
      self.tempObject = Child()
      self.changeTempObjectX(i)
      listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)

  def changeTempObjectX(self, i):
      self.tempObject.x = i

class Child:
  x = None
```

**The Problem:** The `listOfObject` should contain, in theory, 10 instances of `Child` class with different `x` attribute (0-9). What is happening is that the values of `listOfObject` (all of them) are same to the last inserted instance.

I was doing my searching and found out that this has to do with mutability and references. What I think is happening is that what is being inserted to the list is a reference to the previous value which will in turn point out to the last inserted value.

**Tried:** Converting `listOfObject` to tuple and the add operation is like this `self.listOfObject = self.listOfObject + (self.tempObject,)`. I also tried using all types of `copy` which didn't work.

*I'm aware of the structure of the application and I don't need changing it as it will require a big amount of effort to refactor the code. It is pretty straightforward, create, edit and save the instance.*

How can I insert to a list an instance of a class?

Comment: I have tried that and it is not working. (Mentioned in the post)

Comment: To insert the instance of the class to the list. The problem is that since I'm inserting from a reference, the values also changes over time. I can't just simple do list.append(Class())

Comment: Your example works as expected... Thoughj it is missing a `self.` before `listOfObject`.

Comment: can you explain about how you're trying to access the list values, coz i am able to get all 10 values with your code.

Comment: @Faibbus agreed. `self.listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)` is needed.

Comment: The missing `self.` was a mistake on post. The actual problem revolves with the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `x` is an attribute of Child. It is not an attribute of the instance. Therefore, this can be simply fixed by replacing the `x` to `__init__`

```
class Child:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeParent:
  def __init__(self):
    self.listOfObject = []
    self.tempObject = None

  def addObjects(self):
    for i in range(10):
      self.tempObject = Child()
      self.changeTempObjectX(i)
      self.listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)

  def changeTempObjectX(self, i):
      self.tempObject.x = i

  def output(self):
      for i in range(10):
          print self.listOfObject[i].x

class Child:
  x = None

sp = SomeParent()
sp.addObjects()
sp.output()
```

I fixed your code. Your code wasn't working. Better test your minimal example next time. So i can't point out where your problem was, since your example wasn't working. But check my fixed version, the output is corrent.  And you get different objects.

Answer (score 0):

try to execute this -

```
class SomeParent:
  listOfObject = []
  tempObject = None

  def addObjects(self):
    for i in range(10):
      self.tempObject = Child()
      self.changeTempObjectX(i)
      self.listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)

  def changeTempObjectX(self, i):
      self.tempObject.x = i

class Child:
  x = None

testObject = SomeParent()
testObject.addObjects()
for each in testObject.listOfObject:
    print each.x
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to add self before `listOfObject`. It is good practice to use `__init__` function which initializes the attributes. You can try the below program.

```
class SomeParent(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.listOfObject = []
    self.tempObject = None    
  def addObjects(self):
    for i in range(10):
      self.tempObject = Child()
      self.changeTempObjectX(i)
      self.listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)   # ==> Line where you missed self

  def changeTempObjectX(self, i):
      self.tempObject.x = i

class Child(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = None

sp = SomeParent()
sp.addObjects()
print(sp.listOfObject)

listOfObject = sp.listOfObject[:]

for child_object in listOfObject:
  print(child_object.x)
```

Output:

```
[<Child object at 0x7fdc0e13e438>, <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159be0>, 
 <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159c18>, <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159c50>, 
 <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159c88>, <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159cc0>, 
 <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159cf8>, <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159d30>, 
 <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159d68>, <Child object at 0x7fdc0e159da0>]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If you have included self before `listOfObject` then your program is right and should not give you same values and should five you values from 0 to 9. I ran your program

```
class SomeParent:
  listOfObject = []
  tempObject = None

  def addObjects(self):
    for i in range(10):
      self.tempObject = Child()
      self.changeTempObjectX(i)
      self.listOfObject.append(self.tempObject)  # ==> Line where you 

  def changeTempObjectX(self, i):
      self.tempObject.x = i

class Child:
  x = None

sp = SomeParent()
sp.addObjects()
print(sp.listOfObject)


for child_object in sp.listOfObject:
  print(child_object.x)
```

Output:

```
[<Child object at 0x7f713ad220f0>, <Child object at 0x7f713ad227f0>, 
 <Child object at 0x7f713ad22320>, <Child object at 0x7f713ad22470>, 
 <Child object at 0x7f713a9d6198>, <Child object at 0x7f713a9d6e48>, 
 <Child object at 0x7f713a9d6e80>, <Child object at 0x7f713a9c7c88>, 
 <Child object at 0x7f713a9c7cc0>, <Child object at 0x7f713a9d74e0>]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```